# How did they do this? [iPhone layout]

Tags: iphone, layout, swipe

checkout this app:

[image]
 If you swipe left in main image (the black shoes) you can see another image.

Can anyone try this app (Fashiolista, it's free and signup isn't required) and
say me how can I do an effect like that?

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They seem to be using Core Animation to modify the images' alpha and animate the images out and in.

Check out [Introduction to Core Animation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

*edit:

They could also be using UIViews animation API. This is probably even simpler.
[View Programming Guide - Animations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html)

Comment: It seems to be just some labels and image views in the bottom bar. They just get set to some new values when you swipe, so I guess they just start the animation and change the bar properties in the method they set up for handling the swipe gesture.

Comment: Thank you for you support. Another question, in the same app (I hope you've not uninstalled it! :)) look the home screen, where there are all images. How can I do an images gallery like that?

Comment: Looks like a table view with custom table view cells, where each cell just displays three images next to each other.

Answer (score 4):

I've not tried the app, but the way you usually accomplish that is with `UIScrollView`. In order to get the swiping-action to work as expected, you have to set `pagingEnabled` to `YES`.

The hardest part of implementing something like this is handling limited system resources: you'll run out of memory really quick. So you have to implement a queuing system rather like that used in `UITableView`. There are a few projects of this sort on GitHub, but I recommend checking out Apple's dev resources on this; I don't remember the link, but I believe in the last WWDC materials, they had info on how to build this properly.

Comment: Yes, I've thought too to UIScrollView. But if you can try the app you can see that there's a strange effect in swipe, not the standard effect for uiscrollview+pagecontrol (like iPhone dashboard's pages). If you can, try it please. Thanks.

Comment: Interesting. I'll let you know if I get a chance to try it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they are lowering the opacity of the content as it scrolls of using core animation and ease out transition

Comment: So they use UIScrollView without PageControl?